# Summing columns based upon groups using AWK

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have a file that looks like this (except is extremely big with many groups):

```
group1 6
group1 7 
group1 9
group1 3
group1 3
group1 4
group2 5 
group2 7
group3 9
group3 1
group3 2
group4 9
group4 4
group4 5
group4 3
```

I want an output that sums up the totals for every group.  Such as:

```
group1 33
group2 13
group3 12 
group4 21
```

Below is my current code

```
awk -F '|' '{a[$1] += $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' sum.txt
```

Comment: I believe there us a typo your total of group should be `32` here.

Comment: By seeing your profile could see sometimes you don't select an answer as correct one, give it sometime when you have enough responses try to select anyone of them as correct answer.

Comment: Ravinder, thank you for bringing this to my attention.  I'll make sure to be more diligent and select more correct answers.

Comment: delete a question with answer is not very good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. You need NOT to set `|` as field separator since your Input_file is space delmited try following then.

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file
```